# Converting multiple datas into a single string for uploading using json in android

Tags: android, json

I have to submit data from 30 pages into the server.These datas from 30 pages are to be made into a single string and that i have to upload that single string into the server using json.

Each page may contain many answers tht may be either in plain text(value we receive from edit text),from check boxes(yes or no) and so on.....please suggest me a way to add all these data into a single string and upload it using json.

Comment: do you need to upload all 30 pages data at once or one page at once only?

Comment: without seeing the specific data, it sounds like you answered your own question. You're going to use JSON, you're going to pack the answers into their own objects and split everything up into page objects that will be an array item, right? What else is there to say? At the very least you may want to explain what you mean by "pages".

Comment: akash gupta-i need to upload all the data at once

Comment: Dr.Dredel-how can i add the datas of each pages into a single string.I can only upload a single string at the end..but that string should contain everydata

Comment: you can use one static variable and update it in every page and at last send with the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment I suspect that you believe that you need to treat these "pages" as strings that you concat. However, what I think you're overlooking is that JSON is pretty versatile in how you add objects to it.

So, let's say you have the thing that you want to ship to your server and you call it

```
JSONObject myEntireFile = new JSONObject();
```

you can now add stuff to it at any time like this...

`JSONObject page1 = new JSONObject();`

`myEntireFile.put("page1", page1);`

meanwhile you can put whatever you want IN page 1 (cause that's just another serialized container).

You can keep doing this until you're ready to send it, at which time you just call 
`myEntireFile.toString();`
which will convert your object into one long, well formatted, JSON string, that you can then open store for later use.